# How to edit source code of a python project deployed in docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-machine

I have successfully deployed a python project in docker.Please suggest me a way
to edit its source code.

Operating system: Windows 10

Comment: This doesn't have much information. Did you build the image yourself, or get the image from something like Docker Hub, and now are looking to modify its contents?

Comment: I got image from docker hub and using kitematic.Yeah I am looking to modify its contents

Comment: If you need a little change then you can log inside container's bash using `docker exec -it <python_container_id> bash`.

Comment: No I need to edit the core

Comment: You had selected the correct answer before. No need to select another one which says essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker approach is that it is very easy to create a new image, and that you do not modify an image, you create  a new, modified one.

So while you can `docker exec` in your container like 200-OK says, and then `docker commit` the modified image, you should not.

You should definitely have a Dockerfile, and build a new version of your image each time something changes, like when the source code is modified.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

for example, you can name your new image, including the version, something like (extract from the previous link)

`$ docker build -t shykes/myapp:1.0.2 -t shykes/myapp:latest .`

Answer (score 1):

> I got image from docker hub and using kitematic.Yeah I am looking to modify its contents
>   I need to edit the core

Then you need to define your own image, starting with

```
 FROM my_Image_From_DockerHub
```

And you can [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy) your modifications from your disk to that new image, overwriting the python sources need.

From there, [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) then [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) your new image.